# Character Size in Computers

Tags: html, character, font-size

font-size is 1px, does it means that character has height 1px and width 1px, or it has some different meaning. how these lengths put to single characters in html ?

how length of characters works in html and computer screens

Comment: basically standard character font-size in browser is 16px. That doesn't mean your character is 16px height, the real height is much more the line-height. And the line-height depends of the font (ligature, and so on... Clear? hehe... You can find a lot of literature on this subject . Still very basically, your font-size of 16px would give a height like 23-24px. Here in stack overflow, standard font-size is 15px, height is 22.5px. For width it's more complicated mainly because fonts, except monospace, are variables, meaning the i won't have same width as w. In latin character w is the largest.

Answer (score 0):

Font sizes are referring to height, because the width of a character is a variable. For example a lower-case "i" takes less width than an upper-case "W". CSS offers various way to control font width like "font-stretch", "font-kerning"

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-stretch.php
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.php?filename=playcss_font-kerning